# Помогите переписать JQuery в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.size_options li').click(function() {
  $('.size_options li').removeClass('active-size');
  $(this).addClass('active-size');
})
```

```html
<ul class="size_options">
  <li>123</li>
  <li>321</li>
  <li class="active-size">222</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLxVWL мб тут удобнее для кого-то

Comment: Вы не хотите попробовать сами? В данном коде всего-лишь при клике на элемент (найденный по простому селектору) у него же удаляется один класс и добавляется другой. Если это учебное задание, вам полезнее будет найти информацию, как это сделать без jQuery, и когда будете способны делать всё вручную, можете использовать jQuery просто для ускорения работы. Брать же откуда-то скопированный код не всегда хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирать элементы можно функциями:

- [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
- [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Навешивать события через [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Управлять списком классов элемента через [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.size_options');
list.forEach(ul => ul.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if (ev.target.tagName !== 'LI') return;
  ul.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
    li.classList.remove('active-size');
  });
  ev.target.classList.add('active-size');
}))
```

```css
.active-size {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="size_options">
  <li>123</li>
  <li>321</li>
  <li class="active-size">222</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А можно без стрелочных функций?

Comment: Нельзя. Суть ответа не в коде, а в ссылках на нативные функции. Стрелочные функции элементарным образом переписываются на обычные. Вы справитесь.

Comment: Окей, спасибо большое